# XNA Game - Open a Popup or a Custom Game Screen before launching a game

Tags: xna-4.0

Would it be possible to open a custom screen or a popup(modal) in an XNA Game.The idea is to display a few options to the user w.r.t the game and other apps that will be a part of the app suite.

```
public class MyGame : Game
{

    #region Initialization


    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new instance of the game.
    /// </summary>
    public MyGame()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";            
           ///etc;

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Performs initializations required by the game.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        ///I would Like to open a new screen before the actual game
        /// menu is displayed ... also return to this screen after the logic is run
        /// in that screen

        base.Initialize();
    }
}
```

Any Ideas/Suggestions/Samples .
Thanks in Adv.

Krz.

---

Thanks Blau.I tried the DrawableGameComponent solution(copied the code from an article) but in vain.No matter what I do ,just a blank screen is displayed.

In the Game Constructor I put a condition and call the method as

```
if (showScreen)
    {
      LaunchScreen launcher = new LaunchScreen(this, null);
      //Components.Add(launcher); 
      launcher.Show();
    }
else{///constructor code}
```

I also put a condition in the Game Initialize so that if showScreen is flase then execute.(Not sure if its a proper way to do)

The Class looks like this :

```
public class LaunchScreen : DrawableGameComponent
{
    private Texture2D backgroundImage = null;
    private SpriteBatch spriteBatch = null;

    public LaunchScreen(Game game, Texture2D texture)
        : base(game)
    {
        backgroundImage = texture;
        Visible = false;
        Enabled = false;


    }

    public virtual void Show()
    {
        Visible = true;
        Enabled = true;

    }

    public virtual void Hide()
    {
        Visible = false;
        Enabled = false;
    }

    public override void Initialize()
    {

        base.Initialize();
    }

    public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    public override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        //if (backgroundImage != null)
        //{
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(base.GraphicsDevice);
        if (Game.Services.GetService(typeof(SpriteBatch)) == null)
            Game.Services.AddService(typeof(SpriteBatch), spriteBatch);

        Rectangle screen = new Rectangle(0, 0,
                Game.Window.ClientBounds.Width,
                Game.Window.ClientBounds.Height);
        Texture2D lauT2D = this.Game.Content.Load<Texture2D>("Textures/BG");
        spriteBatch.Draw(lauT2D, screen, Color.White);

        //}
        ///SpriteFont font = this.Game.Content.Load<SpriteFont>("Fonts/MenuFont");
        ///Vector2 spritePosition = Vector2.One;
        ///spriteBatch.DrawString(font, "Goodness ME", spritePosition, Color.White);

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
```

I am totally confused on how to initialize the GraphicDevice and the SpriteBatch and open the window before the actual game runs/initializes.
Krz

Answer (score 2):

This is a stack of screens, the top screen is the one that is updated/drawed

You can implement screens for you menu, config, tutorial, solo game, multiplayer game, pause menu....etc.

```
public class ScreenManager : DrawableGameComponent
{
     Stack<Screen> Screens = new Stack<Screen>();

     public event Action<Screen> PopDone;
     public event Action<Screen> PushDone;

     public override void Update(gametime)
     {
         if (Screens.Count>0) Screens.Peek().Update(gametime);   
     }

     public override void Draw(gametime)
     {
         if (Screens.Count>0) Screens.Peek().Draw(gametime);   
     }

     public void Push(Screen screen)
     {
         Stack.Push(screen);
         if (PushDone!=null) PushDone(screen);
     }

     public void Pop()
     {
         Screen screen = Stack.Pop();
         if (PopDone!=null) PopDone(screen);
     }
}

public abstract class Screen : DrawableGameComponent()
{
     protected ScreenManager Manager;
     public Screen(ScreenManager manager) {
        this.Manager = manager;
     }
    // Your template code for screens
}

public class MenuScreen : Screen
{
    public void Update()
    {
       if (ChooseConfig())
       {
            Manager.Push(new ConfigScreen());
       }
    }
}

public class ConfigScreen : Screen
{
    public void Update()
    {
       if (ChooseReturn())
       {
            Manager.Pop();
       }
    }
}

public Game1: Game {

    ScreenManager Manager;

    public override Initialize()
    {
         Manager = new ScreenManager(this);      
         Manager.PopDone += ScreenPopDone;
         Manager.Push( new MenuScreen() );
    }

    void ScreenPopDone(Screen sender)
    {       
        if (sender is MenuScreen)
        {
             Exit();  
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I was looking at loading a DrawableGameComponent or something that is used to create UI Screens. Also I am using VS 2010 Express for Windows Phone;Is it possible to include a Windows Form template.

Comment: I've added source for a DrawableGameComponent that should do what you want... you only have to Enable/Disable it to Show/Hide the form.

Comment: I supposed that a popup beafore launching game means a new window form... I'm thinking you only need a screen manager system... do you want your screen or popup be part of your game?

Comment: I have added the code using the Drawable Game Component in the Question.

Comment: I want it to be an independent reusable screen that can be used with any game or app.It would just have a few links and one to start the game.